# New Child record when a Parent record create

Tags: trigger

We used VF page to create Contact and then used 'SAVE & NEXT' to go to the new Address page create address. Now we want to use 'Standard Contact' page to create contact. I want to open new Contact Address page if a certain condition is met on new contact page. I can use a trigger to create a child record when inserting or updating a parent record. But how can I use user input contact address fields in the trigger?

Comment: Are you referring that you are using standard Contact create page, and you want to capture the address entered on the Contact page in trigger? Which address field are you referring to here?

Comment: We have a Contact Address custom object with different address types. we want to a default address type with user input address line 1, 2, 3, city and Post code.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your question providing step by step what you want to achieve highlighting what is standard vs. custom and also following questions? Like when you say you want to open new contact address page - is it from related list or custom vf page? How is the object and contact related - M/D vs. Lookup? The comments/description is not very clear. Also providing what you have done so far will help here to be able to provide some direction.

Comment: Contact and custom object Contact address has a lookup relationship. When a contact is created or updated after meeting certain criteria I want to create a Contact address related to the contact record. I want to open the Contact Address page to enter in values of address fields just after saving the contact record.

Comment: Do you want to be navigated to the Contact Address screen after the Contact is created, or creating Contact Address behind the scene in trigger while creating Contact is acceptable?

Comment: Navigate to the Contact Address screen after Contact is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the requirements here as captured from the comments:

*You want to create a Contact record, and from its Trigger, you want to redirect it to a custom object for further action*

> You should **not** be doing this

Your earlier approach of using a Visualforce page is the most accurate solution for this scenario.

Triggers operate at the database level and if you see it from a MVC perspective, it's typically at the M level whereas Visualforce page and any redirection is at the V & C level. You should not be attempting or designing your application in a way which does not follow the standards/best practices.